# Bad Request when using ContentType "text/xml" and predefined XML in WCF REST

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

I need to write a REST service that accepts XML documents from a client application. I don't have access to the client application and it cannot be changed.

It sends documents using a HTTP POST with a content type of text/xml; charset="UTF-8".

I have tried two different Operation Contracts and they both have different issues...

First my Host code:

```
    private static WebServiceHost _host;

    public static void ConnectToHost()
    {
        string url = ConfigHelper.GetValue("WebService.config", "WebServiceURL");
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(url);
        Type instanceType = typeof(CXMLService);
        _host = new WebServiceHost(instanceType, baseAddress);
        Type contractType = typeof(ICXMLService);

        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = _host.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, new WebHttpBinding(), "Web");            
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());            
        _host.Open();
    }
```

If I use this...

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SendText")]
    Stream SendText(Stream s);
```

I can receive XML files using a content type of "text/plain" but if I switch it to "text/xml" which is what the client will be sending I get a 400 Bad Request.

If I use this...

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SendXML", Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    XElement SendXML(XElement xml);
```

Then it works with "text/xml" but fails with a 400 Bad Request because the XML has a DOCTYPE element outside of the root. I cannot change this XML file. Here is a sample of the file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.024/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="32232995@ariba.acme.com"
      timestamp="2000-10-12T18:39:09-08:00" xml:lang="en-US">
    <Header>
         /// data here
    </Header>
    <Request deploymentMode="test">
       // data here
    </Request>
</cXML>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic way to stream an xml document to WCF service.

Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "ProfileRequest")]
    Stream ProfileRequest(Stream value);
```

Service:

```
    public Stream ProfileRequest(Stream value)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(value);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        XDocument post = XDocument.Parse(text);
        XDocument response = ProfileRequest(post);

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.ToString()));
    }
```

Test Console:

```
            string filePath = "C:\someFile.xml";

            XDocument testDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(filePath);
            string newDoc = xDoc.InnerXml.ToString();

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(testDoc.ToString());

            string localProfile = "http://localhost/WcfService/Service1.svc/ProfileRequest";

            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(localProfile);
            webrequest.Method = "POST";
            webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
            string strResult = string.Empty;
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
            StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
            strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
            loResponseStream.Close();
            webresponse.Close();

            Console.Write(strResult);
```